# Get all css selectors from SCSS that use a certain variable

Tags: jquery, parsing, sass, aggregate

I am building a live theme editing tool for a website that uses SASS/SCSS for stylesheets. I already built a form with colorpickers that change the page contents when the selected color changes. But now I have to manually compose a large string of CSS selectors that have to be changed when changing a certain value. For example, when I change the "border colors" the jQuery code is like this:

```
$('#preview').find('.article-container, .intro, .error-msg, .block, #footer').css({
  'border-color' : '#'+hexColor
});
```

What I'd really like is something that automatically generates the selector string (".article-container, .intro, etc.") based on the variables used in the SCSS file, so that I don't have to manually do this every time I create a new theme.

So, if there is a SCSS variable $borderColor used in 10 different (nested) selectors, I want  to get all these ten selectors so that I can change all these selectors with JavaScript.

One solution that I could think of myself is to parse the SCSS to a second CSS file everytime SASS parses it, and replace all variables with some sort of "placeholders", but I have no clue if this is possible in SASS and if so, how to do this.

Comment: is selector string change every time? you could store them in array!